# Can you interpret this divergent integral?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, pr.probability, st.statistics, fa.functional-analysis

In [this ArXiv paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9908459) by Wilk and Wlodarczyk (published in Physical Review Letters), equation 16 has essentially the following definition of a function:
$$\text{f(x)=}\frac{c}{2Dx^2}\exp[\int^x_0 \frac{\mu}{t^2}+\frac{1-2\alpha}{t} dt]$$

They claim that with the normalization condition

$$\int^\infty_0 f(x)\,dx = 1$$

it becomes (with some variable changes)

$$\text{f(x)=}\frac{1}{\Gamma\text{(}\alpha\text{)}}\mu\text{(}\frac{\mu}{x}\text{)}^{\text{(}\alpha-1\text{)}}\exp\text{(-}\frac{\mu}{x}\text{)}.$$

---

I can't understand the integral in the exponential function, because it appears to be infinite. Can you help me by telling how can I solve this type of integral?

Comment: Your function $f(x)$ is not defined anywhere, because the integral from zero to $x$ is divergent.  Please check that you copied the formula correctly.  If it can be repaired to something that makes sense, click the "edit" link to make the appropriate change and flag for moderator attention.

Comment: but this is the exact eqn that was in Phys. Rev. Lett. journal. And the resultant Gamma distribution function was one of results of that article. Can it be incorrect???!

Comment: This question was a repeat of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55714. Do not post the same question multiple times - if you think your question should be reopened you can edit it and flag it for moderator attention, or start a thread on http://tea.mathoverflow.net/.

Comment: SMH was unable to edit the previous question because two user accounts were created.  @SMH: you should register, so your work is less volatile.

Comment: I have deleted the previous unreadable question, and revised this one.

Comment: Can you just email the authors asking what exactly they mean by the function $f$, which---as noted above---is not defined in a traditional sense, at *any* (!) point?

Comment: I mean, surely *they* know!

Comment: Why do you expect mathematics published in physics journals to make sense to mathematicians?


Comment: @Gerald: Indeed. On the other hand, Talagrand...

Comment: thank you Mr.Carnahan for your helping and editting my question.:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trouble (as was already explained to you) lies in the starting point $t=0$ of the integral in the exponential. Fortunately, W+W are only interested in steady solutions of equation (15) of their arXiv preprint and these can be written as the function in their equation (16) provided one replaces the starting point $t=0$ of the integral by any starting point $t=x_0$ with $x_0>0$. Changing $x_0$ only modifies $f$ by a multiplicative factor so the normalisation condition saves the day.

Assuming for example that $x_0=1$, one gets
$$f(x)=\frac{c}{x^2}\exp\left(\int^x_1 \left(\frac{\mu}{t^2}+\frac{1-2\alpha}{t}\right) \mathrm{d}t\right)=\frac{c}{x^2}\exp\left(\mu-\frac{\mu}{x}+(1-2\alpha)\log(x)\right),
$$
hence
$$
f(x)=c\mathrm{e}^{\mu}x^{-1-2\alpha}\mathrm{e}^{-\mu/x}.
$$
This is not W+W's formula (18) so either I made a mistake in this post or there is a misprint in W+W's preprint. Note that the function $f_{0}$ written in (18) of W+W's preprint and in your question here is not integrable if $\alpha\le2$ because $f_{0}(x)$ behaves like a multiple of $x^{1-\alpha}$ when $x\to\infty$, hence for such values of $\alpha$, $f_{0}$ cannot be normalized to get a probability density function (even assuming that one got rid of the problem of the starting point $t=0$ as I explained). The function I obtained above is integrable for every positive $\alpha$ and $\mu$.

If $f$ is the density of the distribution of a random variable $X$, the distribution of $Y=\mu/X$ has density
$$
g(y)=c\mathrm{e}^{\mu}\mu^{-2\alpha}y^{2\alpha-1}\mathrm{e}^{-y},
$$
hence $Y$ is a standard Gamma random variable of exponent $2\alpha$ and 
$$
c=\mathrm{e}^{-\mu}\mu^{2\alpha}/\Gamma(2\alpha).
$$
(As I said before, this question belongs to math.SE.)

Comment: All this might mean that (20) in W+W's preprint should be corrected to $q=1+2\tau D$. Or maybe not.

Comment: I want to thank Didier Piau for the answer. It is really helpful. but I think there is a mistake in g(y). g(y) is proportional to
`$\y^{2\alpha+1}$`. I believe that in W+W's article `$\2\alpha$` must be just `$\alpha$` in obtaining the coefficients of the Fokker-Planck eqn (17). so with the point of evaluationg the integrals that you said, I obtain the distribution like this :`$$\text{f(x)=}\frac{1}{\Gamma\text{(}\alpha\text{)}}\mu\text{(}\frac{\mu}{x}\text{)}^{\text{(}\alpha+1\text{)}}\exp\text{(-}\frac{\mu}{x}\text{)}.$$` I have `$\alpha+1$` not `$\alpha-1$`.

  
 

Comment: @SMH: No, $y^{2\alpha-1}$ is correct.

Comment: @Didier: sorry! Can you explain it a little more please?

Comment: @SMH: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables

Comment: @Didier: thank you very much:) it is now solved. It is again a misprint in W+W's article(in eqn (18)). As you said $\text{f(}\frac{1}{x}\text{)}$ is a gamma distribution function, not f(x). similar to the eqn(6). I deduced that there are lots of misprints in printed ISI articles!!! 

Comment: @SMH: The empiricist in me finds rather limited the size of your sample, to reach any valuable conclusion about ISI papers in general. The cynic in me finds rather naive your reaction about the mathematical accuracy of physics papers. Best wishes for your future studies.